# Force SVG tooltip appear when mouse over unfilled area

Tags: svg

Here is a simple SVG code with a tooltip embedded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100"
xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<title>Blue Frame</title>
    <path
    fill="#2E3192"
    d="M75,25v50H25V25H75 M100,0H0v100h100V0L100,0z"
    />
</g>
</svg>
```

It draws blue frame and does nothing more.

The problem is tooltip appears only when the mouse pointer is over the frame. When it moves to unfilled center of the SVG image, then tooltip disappears.

Moving `<title>` tag over the `<g>` tag leads to no tooltip at all.

What have I missed to make tooltip appear always when the mouse pointer is over any point of this SVG, not just over filled parts?

It is just a quick and short preview to show the problem. For example it is very difficult to catch the tooltip on any large image with only a few thin lines.

I know I can place a rectangle that will cover all available SVG space and put anything over it. But this rectangle also needs some color while I need transparent parts of my SVGs to remain strictly transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always put a hidden rect in the background to catch those mouse events you'd otherwise miss like so:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<title>Blue Frame</title>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" visibility="hidden" pointer-events="all"/>
    <path
    fill="#2E3192"
    d="M75,25v50H25V25H75 M100,0H0v100h100V0L100,0z"
    />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How easy it is! ) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest to define `X` and `Y` positions to the rectangle offered by Mr.Longson. Otherwise the rectangle may appear outside of your drawing partially or completely and you would have to catch the tooltip again.

You may get `X` and `Y` values at the `<svg>` tag's `viewBox` parameter, they are the first two groups of digits, the very first one is for the `X` and the second one is `Y`. Other two describes the initial size of the SVG and not needed for this case.

According to your example you don't need to define either `X` or `Y` as they are both equal to `0`:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" visibility="hidden" pointer-events="all"/>
```

But as soon as they are for example `viewBox="-123 456 100 100"` you'll immediately notice that some parts of your SVG still don't show any tooltip. In such case the `<rect>` tag should look like this:

```
<rect x="-123" y="456" width="100%" height="100%" visibility="hidden" pointer-events="all"/>
```